# Diplaying mysql data in a table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table, including the data of my radio station, like this:

```
[id]-[date]-[code]-[song]

1- 12-08-21 03:20:01 - 23 - Bla Bla
2- 12-08-21 03:23:01 - 23 - Other Bla
3- 12-08-21 03:25:01 - 12 - Another Bla
4- 12-08-21 03:27:01 - 12 - Song
```

id is auto-incremental. code is the unique id of every dj.

I want to display the 1-2 together, starting from the first song to last song in a row. It should provide the songs 23 has played in a collapsible view. Or at least this kind of output which just gives the starting and ending times is OK for me

```
23 - 12-08-21 03:20-03:23
12 - 12-08-21 03:23-03:27
```

Can anyone help me on this issue, or at least give me an idea how to accomplist this?

Comment: Q: Is your question how to query the SQL database?  Or something else?

Comment: Two things, first [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) And second, why `code`? Wouldn't `DJ` have made more sense?

Comment: @AlexLunix it's in fact **genre**, since i get the data in the genre field of broadcasting software. i have just given an example of the table.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT song,
    substr(code, 14),
    " - ",
    (select substr(ref_tbl.code, 10, 5) 
        from tbl as ref_tbl
        where ref_tbl.code = tbl.code
        order by id
        limit 1)
    from tbl where code = "23"
```

Something like that should work

Comment: I don't think `SUBSTR` is needed in this query.

Comment: It only displays the songs, without the dates and time. I want to list the items in different sessions seperately.

`23 - 12-08-21 03:20-03:23
12 - 12-08-21 03:23-03:27
23 - 12-08-21 03:27-04:00`

There should be two entries for 23 as in example, if 23 have made two broadcast sessions.